# How do I create a file that includes deleted files?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a script that deletes files older than 55 days. How would I be able to log the deleted files into a separate text file?

The script below deletes files greater than 55 days:

```
forfiles /p "C:\documents\logs" /s /m *.log /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -55
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to **create** a text folder that stores the details of all the deleted files?

Comment: Yes, create a text file with the deleted files and their date. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Create a text file with **the names** of the deleted files and their date...

Answer (score 0):

So you basically need to execute two commands within the cmd execution.  So that means you would use a command separator(ampersand) to execute two commands.  The trick is you need to enclose multiple commands in quotes.  But with forfiles you will need to use the hex code for the quotes per the forfiles documentation.

```
forfiles /p "C:\documents\logs" /s /m *.log /c "cmd /c 0x22 echo @path>>c:\temp\delete.log & Del @path 0x22 " /d -55
```